# Error code 1292 incorrect Date | Time

Tags: mysql, sql, date, mysql-error-1292

Here is the SQL statement I am trying to enter:

```
INSERT INTO comments values (default, 'lars','myemail@gmail.com','http://www.vogella.com', '2009-09-14 10:33:11', 'Summary','My first comment');
```

But I'm getting a 1292 error about my date and time('2009-09-14 10:33:11'). I don't understand, the format seems to be correct. What am I missing?

Comment: I posted my entire query if that's what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
INSERT INTO comments values ('lars', 'myemail@gmail.com','http://www.vogella.com', '2009-09-14', 'Summary','My first comment');
```

You seem to be sending a `datetime` while your field is a `date`. Probably you should change your table structure from `date` to `datetime`.

Comment: Thanks that was it! I guess if anyone that sees this is following this guide:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html

Then make this correction!

Answer (score 1):

Use to_date function.

```
to_date('2009-09-14 10:33:11',yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss)
```